# How to create custom Route childrens of react router v6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm in the middle of a migration from react router v5 to react router v6. One of the main changes on the new version is the `path` property not accepting an array.

So with an original code similar to this:

```
<Route path=["/a-route", "/another-route", "/another-more", "/even-other">
   <VeryBigChildren>....</VeryBigChildren>
<Route/>
```

It has to be refactored to something similar to this:

```
<Route path="/a-route" element={<VeryBigChildren>...</VeryBigChildren>} />
<Route path="/another-route" element={<VeryBigChildren>...</VeryBigChildren>} />
<Route path="/another-more" element={<VeryBigChildren>...</VeryBigChildren>} />
<Route path="/even-other" element={<VeryBigChildren>...</VeryBigChildren>} />
```

Which I think is nasty, difficult to read and hard to mantain.

So I created a small component:

```
export const MultipleRoute = ({ path, children }) => (
  <>
    {path.map((routePath) => (
      <Route key={routePath} path={routePath} element={<>{children}</>} />
    ))}
  </>
);
```

To be able the refactor the original code to:

```
<MultipleRoute path=["/a-route", "/another-route", "/another-more", "/even-other">
   <VeryBigChildren>....</VeryBigChildren>
<MultipleRoute/>
```

However react-router complains about `<MultipleRoute>` not being a valid child for a `<RouteS>` component:

[image]

So, is there any chance to create a valid routes children component?

Comment: That's another of the big changes from v5 to v6 that children of a Switch must be `<Route>` elements and not wrapped ([docs](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5#refactor-custom-routes)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The routes that `MultipleRoute` renders must be wrapped in the `Routes` component, and `MultipleRoute` must be rendered by a `Route` component itself.  Only `Route` components can be valid children of a `Route` component, so `MultipleRoute` will need to take the JSX you want to render on each route.

Example:

```
<Route
  path="/*" // <-- Splat "*" is necessary for descendent routes to render
  element={(
    <MultipleRoute
      path={[
        "/a-route",
        "/another-route",
        "/another-more",
        "/even-other"
      ]}
      element={<VeryBigChildren />}
    />
  )}
/>
```

```
export const MultipleRoute = ({ path, element }) => (
  <Routes>
    {path.map((routePath) => (
      <Route key={routePath} path={routePath} element={element} />
    ))}
  </Routes>
);
```

While it *is* your opinion that just rendering the 4 routes directly is "nasty, difficult to read, and hard to maintain", compared to the code above I would disagree. It's about twice as many lines of code to accomplish less.

The 4 routes directly, for comparison:

```
<Route path="/a-route" element={<VeryBigChildren/ >} />
<Route path="/another-route" element={<VeryBigChildren />} />
<Route path="/another-more" element={<VeryBigChildren />} />
<Route path="/even-other" element={<VeryBigChildren />} />
```

The limitation of using a "multi-route" component like above is where you can only specify one `"/*"` root-level route per path to be matched. If you wanted to "group" routes to render a different component you would need to nest them under other root-level routes.

Example:

```
<Route
  path="/*"
  element={(
    <MultipleRoute
      path={[...]}
      element={<RootChildren />}
    />
  )}
/>
<Route
  path="/foo/*"
  element={(
    <MultipleRoute
      path={[...]}
      element={<FooChildren />}
    />
  )}
/>
```

With this complexity you are better off just implementing normal descendent routes.

Example:

```
<Route path="/*" element={<RootChildren />} />
<Route path="/foo/*" element={<FooChildren />} />
```

```
const RootChildren = () => (
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/a-route" element={<VeryBigChildren/ >} />
    <Route path="/another-route" element={<VeryBigChildren />} />
    <Route path="/another-more" element={<VeryBigChildren />} />
    <Route path="/even-other" element={<VeryBigChildren />} />
  </Routes>
);
```

```
const FooChildren = () => (
  <Routes>
    ....
  </Routes>
);
```

The `MultipleRoute` component is just not necessary.

Comment: My problem on real code is that `<VeryBigChildren />` is not a single component, it has descendants. I guess I can wrap it in a new parent, but I want to focus the refactor on react router staff for now. Start refactoring other parts would make lost focus soon, too many code smells on real code.  Anyway, I get the idea. I can work on something from your response. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Rumpelstinsk I think it's unfortunate that the RRDv5 docs recommended rendering routed content as `children` of `Route` versus using either of the `render` or `component` props as this makes for additional steps to do when migrating to v6 where this is now an invalid practice. For now converting all those `<VeryBigChildren>....</VeryBigChildren>` to `const VeryBigComponent = () => <VeryBigChildren>...</VeryBigChildren>;` (*or similar*) will make the migration easier.